# Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

i want to select value from my database but i got error

```
Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

i don't know where is the  wrong in my code..
this is my code in dbHelper.

```
public Cursor pilihKontak( String nomor ) {
    Cursor c = dba.rawQuery("SELECT idkontak FROM TB_kontak where nomor = '"+nomor+"'", null);
    return c;
}
```

and i want to get the value in other class. 
i use this code.

```
Cursor cursorKontak = data.pilihKontak(nomor);
    idkontak = cursorKontak.getString(cursorKontak.getColumnIndex("k_id"));
```

i've searching and i didn't get the solution of my error.
can somebody help me?
i really need the solution, please help me..
thanks..
Regards..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the cursor to first and "k_id" should be "idkontak".

```
Cursor cursorKontak = data.pilihKontak(nomor);
if (cursorKontak.moveToFirst()) {
    idkontak = cursorKontak.getString(cursorKontak.getColumnIndex("idkontak"));
}
```

Comment: i do the same way ur answer to my other cursor. but i got different error. can u please help me?

Comment: Post a question with code concerning the error and I will take a look. Let me know when you post.

Comment: this is my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381598/caused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-get-field-slot-from-row-0-col-1-fai

Answer (score 1):

The Cursor official [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) say:

Function: `getColumnIndex(String columnName):`

`It returns the zero-based index for the given column name, or -1 if the column doesn't exist.`

So if you are  getting `Index -1 requested` in the error, it means the column does not exist. So try to include the column as @StinePike suggested, or you may try to get all the rows:

```
 Cursor c = dba.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TB_kontak where nomor = '"+nomor+"'", null);
```

Then use the correct column name:

```
 Cursor cursorKontak = data.pilihKontak(nomor);
 idkontak = cursorKontak.getString(cursorKontak.getColumnIndex("CORRECT_COLUMN_NAME"));
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Cursor c = dba.rawQuery("SELECT k_id FROM TB_kontak where nomor = '"+nomor+"'", null);
```